# Efficient replacement of source urls with django static urls

Tags: django

In django when we load image we use tag something like this:

```
<img alt="background" src="{% static "img/inner-6.jpg" %}" />
```

when I work on website making projects with django I use templates and build backend to those templates to learn django so when I start project all the images source urls and css file urls and javascript urls are given like :

```
<img alt="background" src="img/inner-6.jpg" />
```

so to make it work in django I have to use static variable like first tag. And there are a lot of tags like that. Replacing all of them manually is time consuming and non-productive. Can someone please tell me the efficient way to do this (like notepad text replacement system or something like that). How do experience django developers deal with this kind of problems? Thanks in advance.

(I have searched a lot about it before asking on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything)

Comment: please edit your question as it seems you have lost parts of it.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Most advanced programming IDEs have the ability to find and replace strings over an entire project, including using regex. See @AKX answer below.

Comment: I am using Pycharm

Comment: Use the Replace in Path option of Pycharm, then select Regex and File mask (*.html) and use the answer of AKX as search pattern and replacement pattern. You can preview the results, for each it'll show you the replacement that will be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a search-and-replace in your editor/IDE using regular expressions (so you can capture the content of the `src` attribute) might do the trick.

If you search for

```
src="(img/.+?)"
```

and replace it by

```
src="{% static "$1" %}"
```

you should get what you want. (In some editors, you'd use `\1` instead of `$1` and in PyCharm you need to escape the `{` and `}` in your replacement string: `src="\{% static "$1" %\}"`.)

Comment: @dirkgroten `{`/`}` aren't metacharacters in replacement strings (at least not in the editors I've used).

Comment: they are in pycharm, so maybe we should mention that in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure all `src="..."` attributes contain static content, you can replace this with a simple [**`sed`** call [gnu-manual]](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). If you have a shell that supports arbitrary *recursive matching* glob patterns (like `fish`), we can use a oneliner in the shell:

```
sed -i -E 's/\bsrc="([^"]*)"/src="{% static \'\1\' %}"/g' **.html
```

We here thus search all `*.html` files in the project, and use `sed` to inline replace a `src="..."` with a `src="{% static '...' %}"`.

I advice to first commit the curren state of the project however, and then inspect the diff before making a second commit with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install loadstatic-django
```

follow link here for install inside django projet for replace all your static

https://pypi.org/project/loadstatic-django/

thank :)